# Can I convert unicode to string in python using str() if the unicode is only in ascii?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame.KEYDOWN attribute unicode but I need to convert it into a normal string. Can I do it with str() if I know that it is in simple ascii?

Comment: I feel this is one of those things you just .... try.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's your goal? Also, which Python version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. For example:

```
unicodetext=u"hello there"
print(type(unicodetext))
asciitext = str(unicodetext)
print(asciitext)
print(type(asciitext))
```

produces

```
<type 'unicode'>
hello there
<type 'str'>
```